# Use android as webserver on local network

Tags: android, connection, webserver, localhost

Ive seen some apps where you can open your computers web-browser, type in the local IP address to the android device, and access a homepage that hosts from the device.

An example is this app: [Finger Timer - play.google.com](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tw.url.omega.fingertimerfree&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInR3LnVybC5vbWVnYS5maW5nZXJ0aW1lcmZyZWUiXQ)

Does anyone know how this is done? Does Google have an API for this, or do you have any examples that I can start with? Im not a professional developer, so I prefer to keep it simple (few technologies).

What I had in mind was something like this:

- Create a HTML or PHP page on my device
- Feed it with some information from my app somehow
- Host that page, so it can be accessed from any web-browser on any device on a local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this page that is amazingly good. Just what I was looking for. It even has source code, so this is how I can learn faster.
[Android Development Blog](http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/a-bare-minimum-web-server-for-android-platform)
It contains, as the blogger says: "*a bare minimum web server for android platform*".

Comment: Here's an updated link: http://www.devlper.com/2010/12/a-bare-minimum-web-server-for-android-platform/

Answer (score 2):

" Paw Server"  does that.

Here's some [documentation](http://paw-android.fun2code.de/pdf/paw_functions.pdf) on how to use it.

- check out this thread at XDA-Devs which explains the process.
  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=9893301
- on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.pawserver)
- PawServer [Homepage](http://paw-android.fun2code.de/)